# Kotlin flatMapTo does not compile

Tags: kotlin

I want to flat map a Collection of Sets to a single Set. I have the following code which does not compile in IntelliJ IDEA. I can't tell why:

```
listOf(HashSet<String>()).flatMapTo(HashSet<String>()) { it.iterator() as Iterator<String> }
```

There is a very confusing error message on the lambda in the end which says:

> Type mismatch. Required: (kotlin.collections.HashSet<String> /* =
>   java.util.HashSet<String> */) → Iterable<String> Found:
>   (kotlin.collections.HashSet<String> /* = java.util.HashSet<String> */)
>   → Iterator<String>

But they are both completely the same? I am confused as to why that doesn't want to work.

There is also an error message shown on the `flatMapTo` function and says:

> Type inference failed:
>
> inline fun <T, R, C : MutableCollection<in R>> Iterable<T>.flatMapTo (
>   destination: C, transform: (T) → Iterable<R> ) : C cannot be applied
>   to
>
> receiver: List<kotlin.collections.HashSet<String> /* =
>   java.util.HashSet<String> */> arguments: (
>   kotlin.collections.HashSet<String> /* = java.util.HashSet<String> */,
>   (kotlin.collections.HashSet<String> /* = java.util.HashSet<String> */)
>   → Iterator<String> )

*Hope I didn't forget any special characters in the quotes. had to replace < and some * with html entities.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lambda returns an `Iterator<String>`. It's supposed to return an `Iterable<String>`. A `Set<String>` is already an `Iterable<String>`.

All you need is

```
listOf(HashSet<String>()).flatMapTo(HashSet()) { it }
```